# Platformer Collision in JavaScript

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, javascript

I'm making a platformer in JavaScript and this is the collision detection function that I have

```
if(obj2.y > obj1.y + obj1.height ||
   obj2.y + obj2.height < obj1.y||
   obj2.x > obj1.x + obj1.width ||
   obj2.x + obj2.width < obj1.x){
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

So my question is, how do I tell which side `obj1` is colliding with `obj2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your collision function, instead of returning a boolean, return a string so that you can  detect each face:

```
function colCheck(args) {
    if(obj2.y > obj1.y + obj1.height) {
        return "u"
    }
    if(obj2.y + obj2.height < obj1.y) {
        return "d"
    }
    if(obj2.x > obj1.x + obj1.width) {
        return "r"
    }
    if(obj2.x + obj2.width < obj1.x) {
        return "l"
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Depending on the collision, the function will return `u`,`d`,`l`, or `r`, which you can use however you like